# What permissions settings will make /var/www accessible without admin?

Tags: permissions, directory, root

As a webmaster I need fast access to /var/www, what should I set in dir permissions to get rid of 'open as admin' in order to file modification and creation? Yet I want it safe as modificable from my machine only.

Or is there a way to always open everything as admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's my suggestion:

```
$ sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www
```

(changes the permissions to be owned by www-data).  I'm not sure why it defaults to root anyways.

```
$ sudo gpasswd -a $USER www-data   (add yourself to the www-data group)
$ sudo chmod g+rw -R /var/www  #make all files write by group owner.
$ sudo find -type d -exec chmod g+rwx {} \;  #find folders and make sure group has rwx access.
```

logout, log back in.

you should now be able to write any files as yourself.

You could simply chown /var/www to your $USER, though I wouldn't recommend it.  partly because it's insecure, and partly because I think some things will probably break if you do.

Comment: What about security of setting `chown -R root:$USER /var/www`? If it is unsecure, why?

Comment: your webserver runs as www-data which is a limited user.  In case someone can take advantage of a security exploit and get a shell access to the machine as user www-data.  That user is very limited in what it can do.  So it's a bit more work for them to go from www-data to say root.  Which is why usually the apache process runs as www-data, your mail service runs as its own user etc.  You're sandboxing the process a bit.  Most of these users don't usually even have shell access.  or a password set.  (no password == no ssh access )

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sudo gpasswd -a $USER www-data`? We want to add the user to the `www-data` group, not the other way around.

Comment: @kaerimasu Oops.  Nice catch.  I fixed it in the body.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your talking about Apache. If that's the case, I would set the user and group to the user apache is running under (this can be found out with `ps aux|grep apache|awk '{print $1}'`). This will make the files and directory only editable by root. Here's the command to change permissions (if apache is the user):

```
 chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be *less* secure, because a compromised web server process would itself be able to change the files? It seems like the content should be read-only to the web server process.

Comment: @Paul that doesn't work for instances where the system requires the ability to write to the system as the web server (Wordpress for instance).  They can do user:group, where `user` is their user, and `group` is www-data, but that does require you to have your server and access to the login(s) pretty well locked down (i.e. SSH key auth only for a remote server)

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there a way to always open everything as admin?

May be you want:

```
cd /var/www/
sudo -u www-data
```

Answer (score 1):

i used this command

Sudo chown -Rv www-data /var/www

Dont need to logout / end your desktop season.
i log always as root when i want to work in localhost, after i add some files i always use that command.